# Matlab file input

Tags: algorithm, matlab, file

I am asking this as a person with no experience in Matlab.

The project is simple; write a code to analyse a simple truss. The following is what a team mate has been working on - I'm supposed to write the input file:

```
file = input('File Input): ', 's');
run(file)
%Cc corresponds to # of joints and Rc corresponds to # of members
[Rc Cc] = size(C);
%JM is a matrix that contains the joint numbers that each member is
%connected to. The row number is the member number
JM = zeros(Cc, 2);
%x components
Ax = zeros(Rc, Cc);
%y components
Ay = zeros(Rc, Cc);

My_total_length = 0;
Member_length = 0;

%finding JM matrix which stores the joints that each member is connected to
%loop through C matrix and store the joint number each member is connected
%to

for j = 1:Cc
    counter = 0;
    for i = 1:Rc
        if C(i,j) == 1
            counter = counter + 1;
            JM(j, counter) = i;
        end
    end
end

%using JM, loop through C again and create the equilibrium equations using
%the locations of each joint X and Y
for j = 1:Cc
    counter = 3;
    for i = 1:Rc
        if C(i,j) == 1
            %use counter to get x2 - x1 from JM vector 
            counter = counter - 1; 
            %find x and y distance of member and divide it by length of the member 

            Member_length = sqrt(((X(JM(j,2))) - ...
            (X(JM(j,1))))^2 + ((Y(JM(j,2))) - (Y(JM(j,1))))^2);

            Ax(i,j) = (X(JM(j,counter)) - X(i)) / Member_length; ! 13!

            Ay(i,j)= (Y(JM(j, counter)) - Y(i)) / Member_length;
        end
    end
    My_total_length = My_total_length + Member_length;
end
%combine the 4 matrices to create the larger matrix A
A = [Ax Sx; Ay Sy];
%define the vector for the forces on each member
T = zeros(Cc +3, 1);
T = inv(A)*-L;

%OUTPUT

%Find what the load on the truss is by looping through the weight vector and finding the load
for i=1:length(L)
    if L(i) ~= 0
        Load = L(i);
    end
end

%Display load
fprintf('Load: %f N \n',Load)

%Display the forces on the members. Loop through Vector T up to the where reaction forces are
fprintf('Member forces in Newtons: \n')
for i = 1:length(T)-3
    if (T(i)<0)
        fprintf('m%d: %2.3f (C) \n', i, abs(T(i)))
    elseif (T(i)==0)
        fprintf('m%d: %d \n', i, abs(T(i)))
    else
         fprintf('m%d: %2.3f (T) \n', i, abs(T(i)))
    end
end

%Display the last three items of vector T, the reaction forces
fprintf('Reaction forces in Newtons: \nSx1: %2.3f \nSy1: %2.3f \nSy2: %2.3f \n'...
, T(length(T)-2), T(length(T)-1), T(end))

%Calculate cost of truss
Cost = Rc*(10) + My_total_length*(1);

%Display the cost of truss 
fprintf('Cost of truss: $%3.2f \n', Cost) 

%Display load/cost ratio
fprintf('Theoretical max load/cost ratio in N/$: %2.4f \n', (Load/Cost))
```

Now, the problem I have is actually the input file. What kind of file should I save it as? How do I write it in the file? When I'm trying to run the code and need to access the file, how do I write the file name (with `.txt` after)? Some of the information that has to go into the file is below:

```
Sx = [ 1 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0, 0 0 0; 0 0 0]
Sy = [ 0 1 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 1]
C = [ 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ; 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
L = [ 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 500; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
X = [ 0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60]  
Y = [ 0,8,0,8,0,8,0,8,0,8,0]
```

Would truly appreciate any help.

Comment: Matlab has quite a good support for writing and reading files. The question is rather, which format do you prefer? Also, is the data created in matlab and are you going to use the data in any other program? Which file type of file is required in this program in that case?

Comment: Another thing. In matlab many files are written in an alternate language like c or c++. These are then compiled and converted to matlab executables, "mex files". Those are in general much faster than code written in matlab and many of these functions can take vectors. Since the operators (built in) is most likely created in a similar way (or maybe even on a more fundamental plane depending on which operator), this applies for operators as well. This means that vectorizing operations are in general much faster than doing for loops.

Comment: I'm trying to use notebook (I'm not really sure if this is ok though). the thing is, I don't know which file type is required. Also, would you then suggest a format?

Comment: Problem is, this is due in a couple of hours so I don't have time to write the code in a different language then convert it.

Comment: I do not mean that you are supposed to write files and mex them. Rather than a double for loop, do q = `C == 1;` if C is a matrix, to give a logical, which is true where `C==1`. This may require some more work for your code, but just to illustrate the principle. You should also rename the variable `Load`, since `load` is a function and matlab have some "help" that sometimes may associate a variable with the function even if it has the wrong case.

Comment: Are you asking how to edit and save a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fwrite` to write to a txt file. This does however need `fread` and so code to read it into matlab again. `xlswrite` and `xlsread` does the same for xls files.

However, the simplest way if a file only is to be used together with matlab is to use the functions `load` and `save`. You can read the help for them with `help save` or `help load`, but the can save one or more variables to a .mat file.

```
a = 1;
b = 'e';
c = [1,2;3,4];
d = struct('hi',1,'you','e');
save('myFileName.mat','a','b','c','d');
clear;
load('myFileName.mat')
```

You can also write `filepath/filename` (or `\` for windows) where `filepath` is the full path.